# inflating the layout doesn't work

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

Hy guys!

I've a big problem. I am triing to display data from a sqlite database in a listview using a cursoradapter. For this i have an own created layout and a cursor. I used the methods bindview and newview.

My error is something with an id.

**Here is my adapterclass:**

```
public class RouteAdapterActivity extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> arraylist;

    public RouteAdapterActivity(Context context, ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> list) {
        this.context = context;
        arraylist = list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arraylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        DefineRouteActivity routeItems = arraylist.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.outputlayout,null);

        TextView tvDeparture = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txOutputDeparture);
        tvDeparture.setText(routeItems.getAbfahrtszeit());
        TextView tvDuration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txOutputDuration);
        tvDuration.setText(routeItems.getDauer());
        TextView tvTransition = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txOutputTransition);
        tvTransition.setText(routeItems.getUmstieg());

        return view;
    }
}
```

**here is my cursor adapter:**

```
public void getRoute() {
    lvList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvView);
    mdbH = new DatabaseHelperActivity(this);
    cursor = mdbH.fetchallRoutes(mdbH);
    ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> route = new ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity>();
    RouteAdapterActivity adapter = new RouteAdapterActivity(PlanOutputActivity.this, route);

    lvList.setAdapter(adapter);



}
```

**and finally here is my layout which should be inserted into the listview:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/outputlayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/ligthgrey"
    android:onClick="layoutOutput">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txOutputDeparture"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Abfahrt "
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:maxLength="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txOutputDuration"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txOutputDeparture"
        android:text="Dauer"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txOutputTransition"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txOutputDuration"
        android:text="Umstieg"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my cursor Statement:**

```
SELECT f.id, strftime('%H:%M', f.abfahrt) AS Abfahrt," +
                "strftime('%H:%M', f.ankunft) AS Ankunft," +
                "strftime('%H:%M', strftime('%s',f.ankunft)- strftime('%s',f.abfahrt), 'unixepoch') AS Dauer," +
                "r.name AS Route," +
                "count(u.fahrt_id) AS Umstiege " +
                "FROM scotty_fahrt f " +
                "JOIN scotty_haltestelle start ON f.start_id = start.id " +
                "JOIN scotty_haltestelle ziel ON f.ziel_id = ziel.id " +
                "JOIN scotty_route r ON f.route_id = r.id " +
                "LEFT OUTER JOIN scotty_umstiegsstelle u ON f.id = u.fahrt_id " +
                "WHERE start.name = 'Haibach ob der Donau Ortsmitte' " +
                "AND ziel.name = 'Neufelden Busterminal (Schulzentrum)' " +
                "GROUP BY u.fahrt_id
```

**Here are my Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE "scotty_fahrt" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"route_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_route" ("id"),
"start_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_haltestelle" ("id"),
"ziel_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_haltestelle" ("id"),
"abfahrt" datetime NOT NULL,
"ankunft" datetime NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE "scotty_halt" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"folgenummer" integer NOT NULL,
"route_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_route" ("id"),
"haltestelle_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_haltestelle" ("id"),
"abfahrt" datetime,
"ankunft" datetime)

CREATE TABLE "scotty_haltestelle" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"name" varchar(30) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE "scotty_route" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"name" varchar(30) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE "scotty_umstiegsstelle" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"folgenummer" integer NOT NULL,
"fahrt_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_fahrt" ("id"),
"haltestelle_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_haltestelle" ("id"),
"route_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_route" ("id"),
"abfahrt" datetime NOT NULL,
"ankunft" datetime NOT NULL)
```

Please help me!!

Comment: "My error is something with an id." Care to specify what's the specific problem? Also, `while(cursor.moveToFirst())` is not correct as it will loop indefinitely if there are any rows in cursor.

Comment: yeah i added the logcat ... but what should i write ?

Comment: http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/    refer this tutorial

Comment: Does your data table have an _id field?

Comment: jeah i actually build it with that tutorial but i can't find the failure

Answer (score 1):

Its clearly stated `column '_id' does not exist`

> You have to add a field name `_id` in your database to use `CursorAdapter`.

**Solution**

If you don't have field named `_id`, please create one. If you have `id` as a field, just rename it to `_id`.

**Edit**

```
CREATE TABLE "scotty_fahrt" (
"_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"route_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_route" ("_id"),
"start_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_haltestelle" ("_id"),
"ziel_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_haltestelle" ("_id"),
"abfahrt" datetime NOT NULL,
"ankunft" datetime NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE "scotty_halt" (
"_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"folgenummer" integer NOT NULL,
"route_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_route" ("_id"),
"haltestelle_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_haltestelle" ("_id"),
"abfahrt" datetime,
"ankunft" datetime)

CREATE TABLE "scotty_haltestelle" (
"_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"name" varchar(30) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE "scotty_route" (
"_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"name" varchar(30) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE "scotty_umstiegsstelle" (
"_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"folgenummer" integer NOT NULL,
"fahrt_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_fahrt" ("_id"),
"haltestelle_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_haltestelle" ("_id"),
"route_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "scotty_route" ("_id"),
"abfahrt" datetime NOT NULL,
"ankunft" datetime NOT NULL)
```

Comment: do mean i should get an column id in the cursor or create a new in the database?

Comment: @schocka94 can you post your database creation code which has "create table" string.. I just like to see that field names. So that i can suggest some.. :)

Comment: should i create a new column in the database or should contain the cursor an id?

Comment: ok..so where you have declared `"id"` just replace it with `"_id"` and you are done with. and also replace those dependencies.

Comment: should i replace every colmun id to _id?

Comment: @schocka94, one more advice. Please uninstall your application before running modified application code. Coz you have already created tables and this will not overwrite your new one. So this has to be done.. `should i replace every colmun id to _id?` => Yes :)

Comment: and which dependencies?

Comment: Yeah i checked it, but it's difficult to change the column name because its an existing database in my asset folder. Is there any other way except the CursorAdapter?

Comment: You need to create a custom adapter using `BaseAdapter` which has any `ArrayList`. You will find many examples on it. You have to do 2 times coding. First, fetch records from database, store it in arraylist. Second. Display with array list.

Comment: okay i created a baseadapter and i get rows from the cursor but i don't get any layout .... maybe i am inflating it at the wrong place. please look above i update the questioncode